# JNA pointer to strucutre

Tags: java, pointers, dll, struct, jna

I need to pass a struct using JNA.

The documentation that i have has the following information:

```
int rdGetStatusHardware (struct StatusHardware *stat)

struct StatusHardware{
unsigned char   SerialNumber[12];   
unsigned long   HWVersion;
unsigned long   FWVersion;
unsigned long   MemorySize;
unsigned short  BootVersion;
unsigned short  FPGAVersion;
unsigned long   Devices;
unsigned char   Reserved[8];
};
```

I mapped the structure as:

```
public class StatusHardware extends Structure {
    public byte SerialNumber[] = new byte[12];
    public byte HWVersion[] = new byte[4];
    public byte FWVersion[] = new byte[4];            
    public byte MemorySize[] = new byte[4];
    public byte BootVersion[] = new byte[2];
    public byte FPGAVersion[] = new byte[2];
    public byte Devices[] = new byte[4];
    public byte Reserved[] = new byte[8];
    public StatusHardware(Pointer p){
        super(p);
    }
}
```

and this is the method in my interface:

```
int rdGetStatusHardware(Pointer p);
```

Calling the library:

```
Pointer ptr = new Memory(40);
int result = CLibrary.INSTANCE.rdGetStatusHardware(ptr);
```

With this approach I'm getting the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000, pid=3108, tid=5492
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b50
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000
```

Tried other ways that i found on the internet...with the same result and error.

Is a problem with the structure or the interface?

Comment: Are you getting the error when calling `rdGetStatusHardware` or when attempting to access the contents of the structure/memory?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in this case JNA can pass reference to the struct for you, so your method will look like this:

```
int rdGetStatusHardware(StatusHardware p);
...
StatusHardware ptr = new StatusHardware();
int result = CLibrary.INSTANCE.rdGetStatusHardware(ptr);
```

**EDIT**

Access violation could be caused because you're mapping longs to fixed size byte arrays. Long size may vary depending on the platform, so you should always use NativeLong:

```
public class StatusHardware extends Structure {
    public byte SerialNumber[] = new byte[12];
    public NativeLong HWVersion;
    public NativeLong FWVersion;            
    public NativeLong MemorySize;
    public short BootVersion;
    public short FPGAVersion;
    public NativeLong Devices;
    public byte Reserved[] = new byte[8];
}
```

Comment: Your answer didn't work. I implemented both approaches and none worked for me. Giving the same error. Can the error be on the struct?

Comment: Are you sure the `short` fields have not been aligned to 4-bytes boundary?

Comment: i don't know. I don't have access to the library code. I only have this information from the library documentation.

Comment: On windows, native `long` is always 32 bits.  On most other platforms, it will be different depending on the architecture (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: @DenisTulskiy JNA passes structures by reference (by default) in function calls.  It uses them by value (by default) when nested in other structures.  There should be no guessing about where Structure.ByReference or Structure.ByValue is needed.

Comment: Run a snippet of native code that reports to you `sizeof(struct StatusHardware)` and see if it matches the Java structure size.

Comment: @technomage: thanks, I was confused about why ByReference is needed, I'll edit it out of the answer.